# Restore a checked out file that was accidently deleted by another user

Tags: sharepoint-server, restore, check-out, recycle-bin

one of our users deleted a document that was checked out by someone else. As the document was under heavy construction there were many changes since the last checkin. Upon restoring the file, it came back checked out to the original user, butr without the changes made since the last checkin. The document was traceably saved after the last checkin, but even those information is not restored from the recycle bin.

Can anyone give me an indication whether we have the chance to get the contents back? We tried Powershell already, but there we also just get access to the older, checked in Versions.

Comment: How are backups managed in your organisation? Does your organisation have SQL backups of the content databases where the document was stored in? If so, you could restore a content database and retrieve the document from there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. We do not have translog-backups, so this one does not help as the editing all happend on a single day.